# What is the Android Codes to record accelerometer data in millisecond?

Tags: android

I am doing a project that have to record the accelerometer data in a logged file. Can anyone help me with the following codes? What is the android codes that should add in the following codes in order to record accelerometer data? I may hope to get the data every 10millisecond. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AccActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
private SensorManager sensorManager;

TextView xCoor; // declare X axis object
TextView yCoor; // declare Y axis object
TextView zCoor; // declare Z axis object

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    xCoor=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.xcoor); // create X axis object
    yCoor=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ycoor); // create Y axis object
    zCoor=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.zcoor); // create Z axis object

    sensorManager=(SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    // add listener. The listener will be HelloAndroid (this) class
    sensorManager.registerListener(this,
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    /*  More sensor speeds (taken from api docs)
        SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST get sensor data as fast as possible
        SENSOR_DELAY_GAME   rate suitable for games
        SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL rate (default) suitable for screen       orientation changes
    */
}

public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor,int accuracy){

}

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){

    // check sensor type
    if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){

        // assign directions
        float x=event.values[0];
        float y=event.values[1];
        float z=event.values[2];

        xCoor.setText("X: "+x);
        yCoor.setText("Y: "+y);
        zCoor.setText("Z: "+z);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. This is not a question.

Comment: Sorry about that, i did edit the topic and the change it to a question. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

That rate at which you receive data is going to be dependent on the discretion of the operating system, as the data is delivered by events triggering callbacks. It's also likely to device dependent too. You can't poll the sensors at a predetermined rate. The SensorManager API docs state

```
public boolean registerListener (SensorEventListener listener, Sensor sensor, int rate)
```

The rate sensor events are delivered at. This is only a hint to the system. Events may be received faster or slower than the specified rate. Usually events are received faster. The value must be one of SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SENSOR_DELAY_UI, SENSOR_DELAY_GAME, or SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST **or, the desired delay between events in microsecond.**

So you could **ask** for a delay of 10,000 microseconds (10ms), just how often it would be delivered to your onSensorChanged could only be determined by an experiment to measure it.

Comment: NickT,
Did u mean that i just need to choose either one of the sensor delay, e.g SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST and see how fast the OS can receive the data?
I am new at Android, can you please look at the codes that i posted above and give me the codes that i should add? I would like to receive the accelerometer values and save to a file. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, I'd just put 10000 for the 3rd parameter if I wanted 10ms updates, then see how often they actually arrive. (That's how I interpreted the 'or, the desired delay between events in microsecond'. I've not tried it myself but that's how I see it. Good luck.